# Why the below go program gives deadlock error "fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!"

Tags: go, concurrency

I am new to golang and was trying out some typical producer consumer using channels. I understand that both the producer and consumer should write to and read from same channel. But just for experimentation I made them write to and read from different channels like below

```
package main
    
    import (
        "fmt"
        "sync"
    )
    
    func main() {
    
        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        wg.Add(2)
    
        fmt.Println("Starting the main application")
    
        channel :=make( chan int)
        channel1 :=make( chan int)
    
    
        go generateNumbersV2(&wg, channel)
        go printNumbersV2(&wg, channel1)
    
    
        fmt.Println("Waiting for other goroutines")
        wg.Wait()
        //close()
        //close(channel)
    
        fmt.Println("All goroutines finished")
    }
    
    func printNumbersV2(wg *sync.WaitGroup, rc <-chan int) {
        defer wg.Done()
    
        for idx:=0 ;idx<3;idx++ {
    
            val := <-rc
            fmt.Println("******value received from channel ",val)
        }
    }
    
    func generateNumbersV2(wg *sync.WaitGroup, wc chan<- int) {
        defer wg.Done()
    
        for idx:=0 ;idx<3;idx++ {
    
             wc<-idx
            fmt.Println("###value written to channel ",idx)
        }
    
    }
```

And when I run the program , I get the below error.

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

Now , While I understand that both the goroutines are blocked one on the read call to channel1 and the other on write call to channel, so the program would never terminate.
But my question is what if actually am waiting for the values in those channels, should not the program wait indefinitely rather than declaring it as deadlock. What if later on maybe , due to some network read/write, the values arrive and and some other go routines write to these channels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A running program will terminate with deadlock panic only if all goroutines are blocked on a synchronization primitive. If all goroutines are blocked waiting for a channel operation and/or mutex lock, there cannot be a network reception because there are no goroutines listening from a network connection. That also means, in a program with many goroutines, you may have many deadlocked goroutine groups, but the program keeps on running, because there are other goroutines than can still progress.

Comment: ahh I see, so if I understand you correctly. Here main() is waiting for wg.Wait(), printNumbers is waiting to read from channel and generateNumbers is waiting for write to channel. So overall, all the goroutines are blocked, so the program panics with deadlock. And lets say if I have one more goroutine that is waiting for socket read, then the program will not panic with deadlock. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

`generateNumbersV2` is sending data to `channel` - but there are no receiver detected by Go.

`printNumbersV2` is waiting to receive data from `channel1` - but there are no producer detected by Go.

It is correct that the program will wait for data that might arrive at some point, e.g. a network request. If you create such a function, the deadlock error will go away.

A simple fix for illustration purposes:

```js
channel: = make(chan int)

go generateNumbersV2(& wg, channel)
go printNumbersV2(& wg, channel)
```